# Julia tool for graph visualization

Tags: graph, data-visualization, julia, graph-visualization

I use julia programming language for my research. I do some graph processing. For this I use Graphs.jl library which suits me perfectly. But now I need a tool to visualize my graph.

I tried use:

```
plot(my_graph)
```

But it doesn't look so well. You can see it on a picture below.

[image]

Is there any other julia tool to visualize graph better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [`Graphs.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Graphs.jl) uses the [`Graphviz`](http://www.graphviz.org/) `neato` utility to [`plot`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Graphs.jl/blob/0c314e0712ecb954c5f32c5488118031f44a975a/src/dot.jl#L75) the graphs.

You can "enhance" the graphs a bit by defining your own graph function.

```
julia> sg = simple_complete_graph(5)
Directed Graph (5 vertices, 20 edges)

julia> function my_plot(g::AbstractGraph, cmdline_opts::String="")
           if isempty(cmdline_opts) 
               stdin, proc = open(`neato -Tx11`, "w")
           else 
               stdin, proc = open(`neato -Tx11 $cmdline_opts`, "w")
           end
           to_dot(g, stdin)
           close(stdin)
       end
my_plot (generic function with 4 methods)

julia> my_plot(sg, "-Elen=3.0")
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: @skan It would be much better if you asked a new question.  Many more people will see it.

Comment: Most of my quesions are downvoted or closed because someone says it's not useful or it's supposed to be related to other questions. Anyway I've asked at julia forum. Thanks.